# Wordpress get category parents as category array

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

If you look at the documentation for [get_category_parents()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_parents/)
 you'll see that it resturns a string where the names of the categories are seperated by a seperator. Now, I don't know if this is just me but this seems extremely stupid. What I'm expecting is an array of actual category objects. Can't have everything I guess..

What would be the best way to get the parent categories in the format that I want them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one you will get correct result

if your want to get parent category of a post then try this

```
    $parent_cat_array = get_post_ancestors( $post ); //$post is an object or you can pass post id also
```

if you want get parent with category id then try this one...

```
    // determine the topmost parent of a term
   function get_term_top_most_parent($term_id, $taxonomy) {
      // start from the current term
      $parent = get_term_by('id', $term_id, $taxonomy);
      // climb up the hierarchy until we reach a term with parent = '0'
      while ($parent->parent != '0') {
         $term_id = $parent->parent;

         $parent = get_term_by('id', $term_id, $taxonomy);
      }
      return $parent;
   }
```

function to place in functions.php

call this function in your page, post or custom template

```
      $term_parent = get_term_top_most_parent($term_id, $taxonomy);
      // in case of default category then your taxonomy is category
```

Here is the function that return you most parent category or custom taxonomy
Tested!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$categories = [];
$parents = get_category_parents( $cat, false, ',' );
foreach($parents as $parent){
    $categories[] = get_term_by('name', $parent, 'category');
}
```

Not tested.

Comment: Be mindful this will fail if two categories have the same name